# Microphone crackling in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio

I am not very experienced in linux and have this problem with microphone which works fine on Windows. Microphone is external one and when listening to recorded sound (both Sound Recorder and Skype Echo Test) you can hear crackling noise.

I fixed output crackling by replacing

```
load-module module-hal-detect
```

with

```
load-module module-hal-detect tsched=0
```

in /etc/pulse/default.pa but I have no idea how to fix input.

Hardware info:

```
Card: HDA ATI SB                                    
Chip: Realtek ALC272X
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Exactly same problem here :P

Comment: Can you plug it into the line in socket instead of microphone and change you input in sound settings?

Comment: linking to relevant thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2163489

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Try installing alsa-mixer and by using it try to mute one channel of the input (either left or right).

Comment: Didn't work. Tried to mute both left and right channels in Capture section (not at the same time of course) but after recording voice with Sound Recorder only one channel was playing and still crackling.

Answer (score 1):

Try and see if the same mic has the same problems on a different computer.

If the sound is still there then get a new mic.

If not then try and see if there is some dirt or other junk in the port.

If there is no junk in the port and there is still a problem then see if there is a loose connection on the inside of the computer. If you use the mic port a lot then it is most likely crack from the motherboard (it is easy to do this unfortunately).